# jquery animation & responsive issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've created a [bootply with all the html/css/jquery](http://www.bootply.com/S2Y5zdYgHL) for my issue.

Issue #1 - when mousing over quickly sometimes the animation does not revert back. To see this hover over the black squares with "Lorem Ipsum" quickly.

Issue #2 - at cell phone resolutions the animated div slides below the hover div and then jumps into place one past the right edge. It should slide in the same way that it does at larger screensizes. I suspect this may be a CSS issue but am not 100% sure.

relevant jquery

```
// product hover slide left
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.double-square .right').hide();

    //hover over left to slide content to right
    $('.double-square .left').hover(function(){
        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: 'left' };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 350;

        $(this).siblings('.right').toggle(effect, options, duration);
    });

});

// set line height of h4 to height of containing div
$(window).load(function() {
    var divHeight = $('.left').height();

    $('.left h4').css('line-height', divHeight + 'px');
});
```

relevant html

```
<div class="col-xs-6 double-square">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/545/270/people" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="pos-ab">
      <div class="col-xs-6 left">
        <div>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 right">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo deleniti unde possimus maxime facere deserunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div><!--right-->
  </div><!--pos-ab-->
  </div><!--row-->
</div><!--double square-->

<div class="col-xs-6 double-square">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/545/270/people" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="pos-ab">
      <div class="col-xs-6 left">
        <div>
          <h4>Lorem ipsum  <span>&gt;</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 right">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo deleniti unde possimus maxime facere deserunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div><!--right-->
  </div><!--pos-ab-->
  </div><!--row-->
</div><!--double square-->
```

Comment: To avoid the down/close votes, I'd suggest you post the relevant JS here at least. That said, you provided a working example of the problem so +1

Comment: @basic - have added relevant code to the question

Comment: @CreateSean did you answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what is happening is if the user is fast they will mouse out before the slide in animation is complete. Because you are not stopping that animation, it continues and messes up your state.

Normally you could just do something like this:

```
                          // stop existing before continuing
$(this).siblings('.right').stop().toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

but you can't because you are using jQuery ui. jQuery ui effects are not in the normal animation queue. So you are screwed on this I'm afraid. If you did the same animation without jQuery ui as a standard jQuery animation, the above code will save you.

That or you could do with a css3 transition, and then the browser will manage state for you.